# get value from post to sidebar

Tags: posts, php, shortcode, sidebar

I have the following div in my `post`,

```
<div class="my_calss" id="my_id">
    my content
</div>
```

Here, **my_id** is different for each post.

I need to display `my_id` in sidebar into php code. That means,

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wp_value id=1]'); ?>
```

need to assign the above id.

I explained this via **PHP** in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510692/get-id-of-div-php-when-execute). It's not only WordPress oriented, that's why I asked it there too.

Did I explain my question well? if not, please let me know what else can i add ?

Answer (score 1):

You did not explain your question well so I am guessing quite a bit but I think you want something like this:

```
function post_ids_wpse() {
  global $wp_query;
  $ids = wp_list_pluck($wp_query->posts,'ID');
  $scs = '';
  foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $scs .= "[wp_value id='{$id}']";
  }
  echo do_shortcode($scs);
}
```

That is very crude. You should check that the various values are sane before trying to use them, for example.

The idea is to grab the main query object from the page and create shortcodes from the `ID`s it contains.

Answer (score 1):

If the `$post` object is available in your given context (such as, perhaps, a single-post display), you can simply globalize it, then fetch the ID:

```
global $post;
$id = $post->ID;

echo do_shortcode( '[wp_value id=' . $id . ']' );
```

Otherwise, you'll need to drop the ID into a variable from *inside* the Loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // We're in the loop;
    // Store the post ID
    $id = get_the_ID();

    // Other Loop markup goes here, as normal
endwhile; endif;

// Elsewhere in the template:
echo do_shortcode( '[wp_value id=' . $id . ']' );
```